# Forum "read/unread" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've seen plenty of examples and questions on how to do this, but the issue is that they all rely on a massive database on the server-side. I figured I could try to move that to the client-side. Here's what I have:

```
(function() {
var data, pos, read, write, fcnt, tcnt, i, forums, threads, l, fid, id, t, allunread, post;
data = {forum:{},thread:{}};
if( localStorage[USERID+'.forumhistory']) {
         data = JSON.parse(localStorage[USERID+'.forumhistory']);
}
switch(FORUM_READ.mode) {
     // in the initialisation, FORUM_READ is an object with:
     //   mode: "index" for the list of forums, "forum" for an individual forum
     //         "thread" for an individual thread.
case "forum":
    threads = document.querySelectorAll('.f_thread');
              // each thread element has a "data-id" attribute indicating the thread's ID
              // and a "data-ts" attribute indicating the timestamp of the most recent post
    l = threads.length;
    fid = FORUM_READ.id;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        id = threads[i].getAttribute("data-id");
        data.thread[fid] = data.thread[fid] || {};
        data.thread[fid][id] = data.thread[fid][id] || data.forum[fid] || DATE;
        if( threads[i].getAttribute("data-ts")*1000 > data.thread[fid][id]) {
            threads[i].cells[0].children[0].src = "/img/misc/f_unread.gif";
        }
        else delete data.thread[fid][id];
    }
    data.forum[fid] = DATE;
    allunread = true;
    for( i in data.thread[fid]) {
        allunread = false;
        break;
    }
    if( allunread) {
        delete data.thread[fid];
    }
    // Fall through to deal with subforums
case "index":
    forums = document.querySelectorAll('.f_forum');
              // similarly to threads, forums have "data-id" and "data-ts" attributes
    l = forums.length;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        id = forums[i].getAttribute("data-id");
        data.forum[id] = data.forum[id] || DATE;
        if( forums[i].getAttribute("data-ts")*1000 > data.forum[id])
                           forums[i].cells[0].children[0].src = "/img/misc/f_unread.gif";
    }
    break;
case "thread":
              // the last post, #f_post, has a "data-ts" attribute giving its timestamp
    post = document.getElementById('f_post').getAttribute("data-ts")*1000;
    fid = FORUM_READ.forum;
    id = FORUM_READ.id;
    if( data.thread[fid] && data.thread[fid][id] && data.thread[fid][id] < post) {
        data.thread[fid][id] = post;
    }
    break;
}
localStorage[USERID+'.forumhistory'] = JSON.stringify(data);
})();
```

Now, as far as I can tell this works. However, I haven't really been able to test much due to not having anyone else who can test for me (sometimes working alone sucks...). So I'm hoping that someone here will be able to spot any errors in my logic.

Comment: Please explain what you're code is doing before posting it. The title alone is not necessarily sufficient information for any random person on this site to know what you're attempting.

Comment: Basically the idea is that there is an image on each row that lists a thread or forum, defaulting to "f_read.png", which should be changed to "f_unread.gif" if there is an unread entry.

Comment: What happens when your users delete their client side storage?  Everything shows up as unread again?  There's a reason for the "massive database on the server side" approach.

Comment: @Corbin I think that this is an appropriate usage of localStorage. If everything shows up as unread the site still functions - the only effect is that one user has a slightly less convenient experience. And if that user wants to avoid it, they can stop deleting things they don't know the purpose of.

Comment: @st-boost That's definitely one way to see it, however, if I were a user, I would not expect that behavior.  Also, what about a different browser or different computer?  Deleting isn't the only way.

Comment: @Corbin you're right, this can break in completely normal scenarios - between that and the delay in rendering, I'd say a server-side solution is definitely preferable. But I still think of this as an unimportant feature, and therefore an acceptable compromise if server resources are limited.

Comment: @st-boost Fair enough.  However, I'd argue that if server resources are limited, a forum is the wrong thing to be hosting on that server :).  I suppose this all comes down to opinion though.

Comment: @Corbin or the current forum software, yes. But I'd say that's outside the scope of this question ... I'm just here to write javascript ...

Comment: @st-boost I consider general approach to be inside the scope of questions.  Once again, opinion I suppose :).  (Also, there's a reason I posted it as a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: The reason I chose this approach is not because of server resources, but more because the application is already designed to be used in a single browser on a single computer. While of course users are free to use it as they wish, the experience is overall better if they choose a single device/browser to use.

Comment: @Corbin yeah yeah, I get it, you weren't wrong :) Let's just say the best approach depends on the environment, which we don't know much about.

Answer (score 1):

No big issues that I can see, but here are a few tips.

---

When using for-in loops, add a `hasOwnProperty` check, like this:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i) {
        // do stuff
    }
 }
```

Otherwise the loop will also iterate over properties of `Object.prototype`.

---

`data` can more simply and efficiently be declared like this:

```
data = localStorage[USERID + '.forumhistory'] ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage[USERID+'.forumhistory']) :
    {forum:{},thread:{}};
```

---

The switch statement might be more legibly written as a series of if else-if statements (with nesting), but that's mostly a stylistic choice.

---

`data` is, actually, the worst variable name there is. It is impossible to create a less specific name. I would suggest renaming it.

---

In loops where you iterate over an array, like this:

```
var i, l = forums.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    // use `forums[i]`
}
```

If you know every element in `forums` is truthy (not 0, null, undefined, false, or ""), you can use this loop, which is shorter and more efficient, and in my opinion more legible.

```
var i, forum;
for (i = 0; forum = forums[i]; i++) {
    // use `forum`
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tips. If I know for a fact that `Object.prototype` is never extended by any of my site's scripts, it is still worth adding that `hasOwnProperty` check?

Comment: If you're certain `Object.prototype` will never change, then no. But are you really certain? What if you include a third-party script, like an ad?

Comment: I'm not using any frameworks (I hate the things), and any ads will be served in an iframe from a different domain (I have a centralised ad setup for all my projects) so it can't affect the parent window's stuff.

Comment: @Kolink What about browser add-ons? What if the project gets passed off to somebody else, who doesn't know your code assumes `Object.prototype` is unmodified? In the end it's probably not going to matter, but I always feel uncertain knowing my code assumes anything about its environment. Also, I'm so happy I found somebody else who won't touch frameworks :)

Comment: Okay, understood. I'll make sure to add in the check. And yeah, it's always good to find a non-framework-user! Personally, I like to write my own code so that, when things go wrong, I know for a fact that it's my fault.

Comment: @Kolink and on top of that, everything runs faster. But I think the biggest downside to frameworks is that they tend to hide problems that require clever thinking or syntax, making it harder for coders to learn more about javascript as they research and write it.